# Package.resolved gets deleted on branch switching

Tags: xcode, swift-package-manager

Sometimes after executing `git checkout branch` or `git reset another-branch` (while Xcode is open) I find out that the `Package.resolved` file gets mysteriously deleted. I can easily restore it from git or just recreate it from Xcode, but it gets annoying. It seems like Xcode itself deletes it. Any idea *why* it happens and how to fix it?