Xcode loses package dependencies when switching git branches
Since Xcode 15, every time my colleagues and I switch git branches (we do this a lot), Xcode seems to "lose" the package dependencies.  If we don't notice it immediately, we notice as soon as we try to build.
Thanks
This forces us to go into File -> Packages -> Reset Package Caches.  Any suggestions?  Is this happening to others as well?

15.3 and happening to me as well

Related... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78244976/package-resolved-gets-deleted-on-branch-switching

It appears (for us) Xcode 16 has solved this issue.

You can go to File > Packages > Resolve Package Versions to manually resolve dependencies in case of inconsistencies.
It worked for me.
